# How to calculate the number of field accesses from a variable

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
# a: ein Array von Zahlen
# n: die Lange des Arrays
s = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i+=1) {
     s += a[i];
}
avg = s/n;
s = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i+=1) {
if (a[i]<= a[0]) {
        s += 2 * avg;
    } else {
        s += 2 * a[i];
    }
}
return s;
```

The algorithm above is executed on an array a of length n >= 1. Calculate the exact number of field accesses as a function of n for the best case and the worst case. Finally give also the corresponding complexity in O-notation for both cases.

I don't know if I am calculating the number of field access in function of n correctly.

What I understand is every time that "n" or the length of the array is used in the code, it counts as a field access. For this reason, in both cases it would be "2n" (due to the two for loops and because we don't know how many times it will iterate) + 1 (due to the calculation of the average or "avg"). That is to say, for the best case it would be "2n + 1" and for the worst case, the only thing that would change is that the "else" would be executed, but this would not increase the field accesses because "n" is not being accessed, so it would also be "2n + 1".

I also obtained O(n) complexity for both cases.

Comment: Field access would be where the expression `a[i]` is evaluated. This happens exactly `n` times in the first loop. This happens in each if-condition in the second loop (n * 2 times assuming `a[0]` is not cached). The other place is in the statement nested in the else-parrt of the if-statemenmt, which is conditioned on the size of each element relative to the first element (which can happen 0 times or up to `n` times and `n/2` times on random data on average).

Answer (score 0):

> What I understand is every time that "n" or the length of the array is
> used in the code, it counts as a field access.

No. A field access is something like `a[]`. n is definitively the determining factor, in the sense that it represents the size of the data and that we choose to consider the number of accesses to the data as the measure of the complexity of the algorithm.

> [...] and because we don't know how many times it will iterate

In fact, we know exactly how many times it will iterate : it's **n** times for each loop in your program, because there is no call to `break()` or `return()` in your loops (see below)

Let's examine your code:

```
# a: ein Array von Zahlen
# n: die Lange des Arrays
s = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i+=1) {
     s += a[i];                 /* n calls to a[] */
}
avg = s/n;
s = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i+=1) {
if (a[i]<= a[0]) {              /* 2n calls to a[] */
        s += 2 * avg;
    } else {
        s += 2 * a[i];          /* worst: all a[] are > a[0] so: (n-1) calls
                                   best: all a[] are <= a[0] so: 0 calls */
    }
}
return s;
```

In conclusion:

- Best case : n+2n = 3n
- Worst case: n+2n+(n-1) field accesses = 4n-1

So the complexity is **O(n)**.

Comment: Why is a[ ] the field access? And why is (n-1) at the worst case and not just n?

Comment: a[] is the definition of a field access : you access an element of the array a by calling a[i]. You only count accesses on the thing you want to measure, that is : the data, input of your algorithm. Other accesses like i or s effectivly exists but are not the deterministic factor of your algorithm. You want to express the time complexity of your algorithm based on the size of your input data which is array 'a'.

Comment: (n-1) because you always has the case i = 0, so in this case a[i]=a[0], so you don't call the 'else' clause of your if, so you have a total of (n-1) a[] access instead of 'n'. Note that this is not important when looking for the O() complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However I think you mean (n-1) calls for the best case where the condition of the if statement is met, because in the worst case, as you said, all a[] are > a[0], that means that the else will be executed for the worst case, right?